# creating .lib file in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static-libraries

hi i am trying to create a static library which results in a .lib file. i have file1.h and file1.cpp. file1.cpp has codes which needs function defined in file2.cpp and file2.h. in my project (which in project properties->configuration i have defined my project as a static library). after i compile is see file2.obj and file1.obj files in the release folder. i do not
see any .lib file. where and how should i change in the visual studio 2010 so that i get a .lib file with the function that was defined in file file1.cpp.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the output file is specified in:

```
Configuration Properties -> Librarian -> General -> Output File
```

It may have a value other than the location of your .obj files so - even though it's creating a .lib - it's not where you expect it.

Also, watch the "Output" window when you build. It should echo where it's writing the .lib file.